# How to output column values from pyspark dataframe into string?

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm working with a dataset and want to create a textblob of all values of a particular column called 'text'. I tried the following methods:

```
xp = positive.select("text").collect().map(_(0)).toList
#positive is the dataframes name, 'text' is the column name
xp = " ".join(positive['text])
```

None of these methods have worked for me thus far and return the error

```
'list' object has no attribute 'map'
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using Scala syntax. The `list` returned by `collect` contains `Row` objects; you can simply access the `text` attribute of each `Row` using a *generator expression*, rather than using `map` (which is not a method of `list`, in any case):

```
' '.join(row.text for row in positive.select('text').collect())
```